# Spring Boot datasource doesn't go to BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to make a proxy for my dataSource, but the following is never invoked with bean data source object and *bean instanceof DataSource* is always *false*:

```
@Component
public class DatasourceProxyBeanPostProcessor implements 
BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
            final ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            factory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
            factory.addAdvice(new ProxyDataSourceInterceptor((DataSource) bean));
            return factory.getProxy();
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I have the following config for postgres:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: ***
    password: ***
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=myschema
```

Spring Boot: v1.5.x

Any idea why I don't get inside the block *bean instanceof DataSource*?

Comment: can you tell what comes to the variable 'bean' when you invoke postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) ? is it null?

Comment: I have huge number of beans. Spring invokes postProcessAfterInitialization for each bean. So, it's not null. The problem is that it is not invoked with the bean that fits "bean instanceof DataSource"

Comment: so its clear that your DataSource bean is not present in the spring context. Even though you pass the configurations, did you initialize any DataSource bean in your application at all? like 
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
if not I think its the problem, even though you have provided the configuration, there's no such bean.

Comment: @Damith, I haven't initialised any DataSource directly. I only made yaml configs. I work with my DB using EntityManager and it works fine with that config.

Comment: That's the thing. Since you are only initializing your configurations, your spring context does not have a bean of a DataSource Implementation. Of course it does have DataSourceProperties bean as you provided the configurations. And that way you can work with entity manager. But if you want to have this logic, you have to however initialize a DataSource implemented bean. https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/package-summary.html

Comment: If you want, you can put a print statement for the `beanName` and see what beans are getting passed through the `postProcessor`

Comment: Which ‘DataSource’ are you checking, do you have the correct package?

Comment: if (beanName.equals("dataSource")) {} to debug to see the current bean instance

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [`DelegatingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html)?

We can probably solve your problem with the proxy, but this class is likely meant to solve your root problem:

> This class is meant to be subclassed, with subclasses overriding only
>   those methods (such as [`getConnection()`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html#getConnection--)) that should not simply
>   delegate to the target DataSource.

Comment: When I create such a bean I get : Error creating bean with name 'delegatingDataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: If you want to go down this route for your solution, I'd post your configuration. You might have made a circular reference if you're injecting a DS and the only one in your context is the delegating DS

Comment: Yes, please, post it

Comment: I meant to please post your configuration